# Memory Leak - Valgrind - "0 bytes lost in 59 blocks"

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

Valgrind says that I have a memory leak of 59 bytes in 59 blocks because of my function ft_strdup :

```
char            *ft_strdup(const char *s)
{
    char    *dup;
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    dup = (char *)malloc((ft_strlen(s) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if (!dup)
        return (NULL);
    while (s[i])
    {
        dup[i] = s[i];
        i++;
    }
    dup[i] = '\0';
    return (dup);
}
```

But when I change the size of the allocation to :

`dup = (char *)malloc(ft_strlen(s) * sizeof(char));`

Valgrind shows me this result :

```
==36929==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 59 blocks
==36929==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Why the 59 blocks still shows up instead of 0 blocks since there isn't any bytes lost?

Comment: Of course the caller should free the memory returned by your function. Your function looks correct to me.

Comment: Your second allocation is wrong because you really need that terminating null character.

Comment: two things I see here: (1) as said by @PaulOgilvie, the pointer returned by your function, should be released by the caller, and you need to allocate space for the string + the null terminator character. (2) something tell me that your function ft_strlen is returning 0; that explain that for the first allocation 59 bytes are leaked matching with the number of allocations (not released); when you change to the wrong second allocation you are allocating 0 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the size of the allocation to:

```
dup = (char *)malloc(ft_strlen(s) * sizeof(char));
```

you're overwriting the memory you haven't allocated with a termination `\0` character, which is pretty much the source of your problem.

Agree, valgrind could have given the better diagnostic, but it could have given the worse as well.

Comment: What about his first form of allocation?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie with his first form there are no complaints from valgrind